# Dimensions of a window don't match

Tags: java, swing, jframe

```
class Main 
{     
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
     Window h = new Window(100,100);            
    }        

}



class Window
{
    private JFrame frame;

    public Window(int width,int height)
    {
        Rectangle dim = new Rectangle();

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(0, 0);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.getBounds(dim);

        System.out.print(dim); 
    }
}
```

This program creates a window of width and height specified in the constructor, then measures and "echoes" it's dimensions.

> run:
>       java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=132,height=100]

Could you explain why is a real window wider by 32px?

Comment: may be 32px for close button!!!

Comment: instead of setting the size of the frame, you should set the size of the content pane.  And instead of setting the size of the content pane, you should put content into it that suggests a size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `JComponent` has default minimum size, and in your case, the minimal width is 132px. To solve the problem, you may either increase `window`'s width to at least 132, or add `frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 100))` before `frame.setSize(width, height)`.

Comment: Nothing happens after placing frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height)); before setting JFrame size.

Comment: That's weird, it works on my machine. Try: `new Window(200,100)` or try: `frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(50, 100))` and see what happens.